# Java applet game runs at different speeds on different computers

Tags: java, applet

I have built a Java game (applet) and have put it on a [test website](http://www.breakoutgame.hostzi.com/). I can't display the whole code on here as its to big, but the game runs at 20 frames/seconds as it sleeps in the main loop for 50 milliseconds. I have run the game on three computers, two of them are faster then the other on its processor speed and ram. The other one is a small notebook and it doesn't run my game properly. My game is like a breakout game with a paddle and a ball, the problem is, when the ball move it slows down and speeds up a regular Patton (it is extremely noticeable). This happens on the small computer, but not on the other two.

The Game: 
To make this game I followed this [series on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWESIsSB1qY).

So basically:

There are three computers:

- Notebook (2GB of RAM, and 1.60 GHz) - Run game with a problem (Slow and fast ball)
- Laptop (4GB of RAM, 2.7 GHz) - Runs game as fast as the desktop (perfectly)
- Desktop (16GB of RAM, UNSURE but MUCH higher then 2.7 GHz) - Runs game perfectly

With the knowledge above I can rule out then the game is **not** dependent on the processor speed and must be something else. Could it be because of the notebooks processor, as its two weak to process it? but it is 1.6 GHz, so i don't see how it to week for a little game. I really don't know what to think, any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: you must correct collision algorithm ;)

Comment: Not just the collision algorithm, but you will need to correct the movement algorithm. The distance traveled should depend on the System clock, not the estimated time slice.

Comment: Yeah, its in it early stages;)

Comment: I basically just have the ball moving so many pixels every time the program goes through my main loop, and the loop sleeps 50 milliseconds every time it goes round. Is this not an effective way of moving the ball, or right way?

Comment: Please provide your main game loop, and algorithm for calculating the positions of game elements that concern you.

Comment: The code is not written perfectly, and the whole algorithm is slip over many different classes. I am just trying to work out why my game is slower in ways on one computer to another, despite me having the main loop sleeping for a certain amount of time (regulating the frame/second). I am not an expert on java hence why i followed a youtube tutorial, but i do know a few things. Maybe you could take a look at the tutorial and find out what algorithms he is using, if you could spare the time.

Comment: can you copy important code to http://pastebin.com/ ? It would be much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just sleeping between cycles, try something like this:

...

```
final long timeSlice = 100;
while(true) {
  long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() ;
  doMyStuff();
  long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  sleep(Math.max(timeSlice + startTime - endTime, 0))
} // end while()
```

...

You will end up with each cycle taking about the same time.